# Ligth clock with spaceships side-by-side

Tags: homework-and-exercises, relativity, time

In the reference frame of an observer, two spaceships travel in a straight direction (e.g. x axis) at a very high velocity and side-by-side; the distance between them is always d (km) = c (km/s) x 0.1 (s).
At its time zero, spaceship one begins the emission of one photon each 0.1 (s) to the spaceship two (parallel to y axis).
The wavelength of one photon is λ(i) = 0.001 x λ(i-1) and the first photon has a wavelength of λ(0).

Question 1: Find the wavelength of the first photon detected by spaceship two.

Question 2: Suppose that the observer can see each photon. What does he will see?
This is not homework.

Comment: Homework or homework-like the same rules apply. You need to ask about a physics concept. We don't know what you know and what you don't so we can't help, all we do is solve a problem that is just ...like ... homework. So show what you know, make an effort and ask about a physics concept.

Comment: My question is about the mind experience know as Light Clock. I don't understand it and my intent is to clarify it.

Comment: Question 1 is off topic because it is homework-like. Question 2 is unclear because the experimental setup was unclear. Consider drawing a diagram. Alternatively, check around on the site. This may have been answered before

Comment: I don´t kow how to post figures... And I am a 69 years old guy...

Comment: @jim If a photon is fired to an orthogonal direction of the movement of the source what will be the direction traveled by the photon?

Comment: Is it orthogonal as viewed by the source or by a stationary external observer?

Comment: as viewed by the source

Comment: If it fires a photon orthogonal to its heading, it will travel orthogonal to the source's heading from the POV of the source. From the POV of an outside observer, it will travel not orthogonal to the motion of the source, but slightly along its direction of motion.

Comment: To the POV of an outside observer the direction will be the one that we could have by adding the vector of the velocity of the source with the vector of c at the orthogonal to the velocity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer question 2:

If it fires a photon orthogonal to its heading, it will travel orthogonal to the source's heading from the POV of the source. From the POV of an outside observer, it will travel not orthogonal to the motion of the source, but slightly along its direction of motion.

This can be easily intuited because in its own frame, the source is at rest. This means when one spaceship fires a photon to the adjacent one, the photon will hit the other ship. From the point of view of an outside observer this must still hold true, but since both ships are moving, the outside observer will not see the photon as fired orthogonal to the direction of motion; it will be angled such that it has the same velocity as the spaceships in their direction of motion, and thus can eventually hit the second ship.

The speed of the photon must, obviously, still be $c$. To find the velocity of the photon orthogonal to the direction of motion of the spaceships, all you need is a little trigonometry.

$$c^2-v^2=x^2$$

If you know $c$ and $v$ (the ship's velocity), then solve for $x$ for the component of the photon's velocity orthogonal to the direction of motion as seen by the observer. Note, this only works out so well when the moving ship emits the photon perpendicular to its heading

Comment: From the point of view of an outside observer this must still hold true: That's the key! Thanks.